# Why are input objects getting outside the div?

Tags: html, css

Note: I am an super-novice or amateur in CSS.

I am having a css issue. Here is the html:-

```
<div class="obj-cont">
    <div class="lbl-cont"><label>Post Title :</label></div>
    <div class="input-cont"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""  required/></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:-

```
.form-container{border: 1px #ccc solid; border-radius: 5px; height: auto; padding: 10px; width: 70%; margin-left: 10%;}
.obj-cont{padding: 5px; width: 300px; height:auto; border: 1px solid #000;}
.lbl-cont{float:left; width: 80px}
.input-cont{float:left; width: 80px}
```

The result is coming like this:-
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `float` on the `.lbl-cont` and `.input-cont`. If you float a element it breaks out of the block positioning.

**You can use the following code instead:**

```css
.form-container {
  border: 1px #ccc solid; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  height: auto; 
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 70%; 
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.obj-cont {
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 300px; 
  height:auto; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lbl-cont {
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 80px;
}
.input-cont {
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="obj-cont">
  <div class="lbl-cont">
    <label>Post Title :</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-cont">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" required/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always have to clear after floating.
Means, you have to add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the floated elements and inside the containing element.
In your case:

```
<div class="obj-cont clearfix">
  <div class="lbl-cont"><label>Post Title :</label></div>
  <div class="input-cont"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""  required/></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding an extra html tag just for clearfix is not recommended. The CSS should be separate from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `.lbl-cont` and `.input-con` are floated elements, so the parent element (`.obj-cont`) needs to be cleared to have height.

The below code is from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/:

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Add the clearfix class to obj-cont.

```
<div class="obj-cont clearfix">
  <div class="lbl-cont"><label>Post Title :</label></div>
  <div class="input-cont"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""  required/></div>
</div>
```